# enumeration of all Maximal independent set on trees

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

what is the algorithm for enumerating  all maximal independent set on trees (without the constaint of  lexicographic order) .
It 's very natural to find an algorithm faster than $ O(3^{n/3})$ on trees .

In fact ,in  trees we have at most $O(2^{n/2})$ maximal independent set but I try to find an algorithm to enumerate those .

Comment: *The* algorithm? Which one? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: The number of MIS in tree is at most $ 2^{n/2} $  . So I try to find an algorithm to compute all MIS in a faster time that the general algorithm with running time $O(3^{n/3})$. I think we can have an algorithm to enumerate all MIS on tree with only a running time $O(2^{n/2})$

Comment: We have an algorithm in polynomial delay  ( Y. H. Chang, Jia-Shung Wang, Richard C. T. Lee:
Generating All Maximal Independent Sets on Trees in Lexicographic Order. Inf. Sci. 76(3-4): 279-296 (1994) .

But I don't need the lexicographic order . I need an algorithm generating all maximal independent sets on trees without the constraint of lexicographic order

Comment: Please edit the question to incorporate all requested information.  Don't just leave information in the comments -- the comments exist only to help you improve your question, and can disappear at any time.  People shouldn't need to read the question to understand your question.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Ah, my bad. I'll remove the statement. (Still, I think "at most" implies a "$\leq$" which an $O$ can never give, due to the constant factor, and because the bound may not be tight. The language feels imprecise as a consequence.)